# Jmeter property rmi configuration

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter bin directory jmeter.property file, there are similar keys, I don't understand different each other.

```
client.rmi.localport
server.rmi.port
server.rmi.localport
server_port
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

- `client.rmi.localport` - Parameter that controls the RMI ports used by RemoteSampleListenerImpl and RemoteThreadsListenerImpl (The Controller)
- `server.rmi.port` - To change the default port (1099) used to access the server.
- `server.rmi.localport` - To use a specific port for the JMeter server engine, define this property before starting the server.
- `server_port` - RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port).

Where:

- `client` (or `Controller`) == JMeter Master
- `server` == JMeter Slave

More information:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: Thank a lot my friend, In linux clients, without the need for adjustment tests run remotely. But in windows clients, there are some issues. Firstly, client can not access sever. Adding server.rmi.localport this issue solved but in spite of finished of test, master machine don't finish test.